# `nix-build` fails because Python wants something that's unavailable, without saying what it wants

Tags: python-2.7, sandbox, nix, nixos

(At least I *think* that's the problem.)

## The error

When I run `nix-build -A serialosc` from the root of nixpkgs, nix prints the following:

```
[jeff@jbb-dell:~/nix/nixpkgs-fork]$ nix-build -A serialosc
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/p40wvn28grb8nrcd6scbxhhjqw4495kk-serialosc.drv
building '/nix/store/p40wvn28grb8nrcd6scbxhhjqw4495kk-serialosc.drv'...
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/5zj802wfjd0ima92lpzzsqdjqvrnrwf9-serialosc
source root is serialosc
patching sources
configuring
configure flags: --prefix=/nix/store/b6qzvzmwjdi29nnzc769904wc0mj1cds-serialosc configure
Setting top to                           : /build/serialosc 
Setting out to                           : /build/serialosc/build 

Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : gcc 

Checking for working poll()              : yes 
Checking for libudev                     : yes 
Checking for libmonome                   : yes 
Checking for liblo                       : yes 
Checking for function strdup             : yes 
Checking for function _strdup            : not found 
Checking for function strndup            : yes 
Checking for function strcasecmp         : yes 
Checking for header unistd.h             : yes 
Checking for header dns_sd.h             : yes 
Checking for library dl                  : yes 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/build/serialosc/.waf-1.8.5-3fc7b0f5070c04bfd3f2489448471a84/waflib/Scripting.py", line 103, in waf_entry_point
    run_commands()
  File "/build/serialosc/.waf-1.8.5-3fc7b0f5070c04bfd3f2489448471a84/waflib/Scripting.py", line 164, in run_commands
    ctx=run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/build/serialosc/.waf-1.8.5-3fc7b0f5070c04bfd3f2489448471a84/waflib/Scripting.py", line 155, in run_command
    ctx.execute()
  File "/build/serialosc/.waf-1.8.5-3fc7b0f5070c04bfd3f2489448471a84/waflib/Configure.py", line 92, in execute
    super(ConfigurationContext,self).execute()
  File "/build/serialosc/.waf-1.8.5-3fc7b0f5070c04bfd3f2489448471a84/waflib/Context.py", line 92, in execute
    self.recurse([os.path.dirname(g_module.root_path)])
  File "/build/serialosc/.waf-1.8.5-3fc7b0f5070c04bfd3f2489448471a84/waflib/Context.py", line 133, in recurse
    user_function(self)
  File "/build/serialosc/wscript", line 259, in configure
    stderr=devnull).decode().strip()
  File "/nix/store/lbrpma3528hq7gwn8ffbnwaxvsqah0bb-python-2.7.17/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 216, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/nix/store/lbrpma3528hq7gwn8ffbnwaxvsqah0bb-python-2.7.17/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/nix/store/lbrpma3528hq7gwn8ffbnwaxvsqah0bb-python-2.7.17/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
builder for '/nix/store/p40wvn28grb8nrcd6scbxhhjqw4495kk-serialosc.drv' failed with exit code 2
error: build of '/nix/store/p40wvn28grb8nrcd6scbxhhjqw4495kk-serialosc.drv' failed

[jeff@jbb-dell:~/nix/nixpkgs-fork]$
```

## My suspicion

The problem appears to arise in `lib/python2.7/subprocess.py`. I found [a version of that file](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py) online, and the [definition of `_execute_child`](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L1111) seems to make reference to some absolute paths -- for instance, in this passage:

```py
    if shell:
        args = ["/bin/sh", "-c"] + args
        if executable:
            args[0] = executable
```

Therefore my guess is that Nix is building in a sandbox that doesn't offer whatever Python expects. But the error doesn't tell me what Python was hoping to find.

## The context

(You might not need this information.)

I'm trying to [build serialosc](https://monome.org/docs/serialosc/raspbian/) on NixOS 19.09. Here's my [fork of nixpkgs](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/nixpkgs/tree/2bbd131811991bec9ae6b296b5cd1441640c306c), including my [broken recipe for `serialosc`](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/nixpkgs/blob/2bbd131811991bec9ae6b296b5cd1441640c306c/pkgs/development/libraries/serialosc/default.nix). The fork also includes my `libmonome` package, which works, and which `serialosc` depends on, and which is not yet part of the official `nixpkgs` repo. I've given hard links to the specific commit; they shouldn't change when I update the fork.

Comment: Personally, I would debug this by using sysdig to trace what the failing `execve()` call is trying to invoke. (On NixOS, you might need to be a little careful about which kernel package you're using -- there was a while, at least, where sysdig would fail to build with the default kernel in nixpkgs; but hopefully that's fixed by now, and if not fixed upstream, it's *fixable* in any event).

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting from
https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-build-fails-because-python-wants-something-thats-unavailable-without-saying-what-it-wants/5675/2
so that it could help people who only find this, answer might continue on NixOS discourse. I tried to keep it helpful for general NixOS writing a derivation debugging, with some Python bits

## fetchgit

First, let's help with the `fetchgit` part in your recipe

```
  src = fetchgit {
    # Once, it seemed to finish, and I don't know how! Then it crashed with:
    # Switched to a new branch 'fetchgit'
    # removing `.git'...
    # hash mismatch in fixed-output derivation '/nix/store/5zj802wfjd0ima92lpzzsqdjqvrnrwf9-serialosc':
    # wanted: sha256:1vqcxi32wc4pklbddllflkaigkfvd4ykwrjqccayvrk10dx1sna3
    # got:    sha256:1zmzjasv21ix7i7s58a31k0025ji32hv2jm2ww6s0xhjmr5ax34j

    # This way it [[gets pretty far]].
    # The fetchSubmodules value I set again seems to have no effect.
    url = https://github.com/monome/serialosc.git;
    rev = "v1.4.1";
    sha256 = "1zmzjasv21ix7i7s58a31k0025ji32hv2jm2ww6s0xhjmr5ax34j";
```

Perhaps there was a force push? Not sure why it would stop working with the hash

I found that the fetchSubmodules has no effect if you have the hash of the one without the submodules, use `nix-prefetch-git --fetch-submodules https://github.com/monome/serialosc`  which gives

```
{
  "url": "https://github.com/monome/serialosc",
  "rev": "cec0ea76b2d5f69afa74d3ffc14a0950e32a7914",
  "date": "2019-06-09T21:46:13+02:00",
  "sha256": "03qkzslhih72idwafgfxmkwp5v3x048njh0c682phw2ks11plmbp",
  "fetchSubmodules": true
}
```

so use

```
fetchgit {
  url = https://github.com/monome/serialosc;
  rev = "cec0ea76b2d5f69afa74d3ffc14a0950e32a7914";
  # or rev = version; but that might break with force pushes
  sha256 = "03qkzslhih72idwafgfxmkwp5v3x048njh0c682phw2ks11plmbp";
  fetchSubmodules = true;
}
```

## wafHook

There is a (slight) `wafHook` documentation in https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/

## Debugging error

It seems to want to do `git` stuff, here is how I debugged it:

```
$ nix-shell https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/nixpkgs/archive/2bbd131811991bec9ae6b296b5cd1441640c306c.tar.gz -A serialosc --pure
nix-shell $ mkdir /tmp/delme-serialosc
nix-shell $ cd !$
# To find out what a build would do
nix-shell $ type genericBuild
...
# Doing the `if [ -z "${phases:-}" ]; then ...` bit gives us `echo $phases`
# unpackPhase patchPhase configurePhase buildPhase checkPhase installPhase fixupPhase installCheckPhase distPhase
nix-shell $ ${unpackPhase:-unpackPhase}
nix-shell $ cd $sourceRoot
nix-shell $ ${patchPhase:-patchPhase}
nix-shell $ ${configurePhase:-configurePhase}
# Error happens here
nix-shell $ type ${configurePhase:-configurePhase}
# Do the steps until you find it stops in `python ...`
# Python debug info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html
nix-shell $ python -m pdb "$wafPath" "${flagsArray[@]}";
(Pdb) continue # or cont, or just c
...
(Pdb)  break /nix/store/lbrpma3528hq7gwn8ffbnwaxvsqah0bb-python-2.7.17/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py:1047
(Pdb) continue
> /nix/store/lbrpma3528hq7gwn8ffbnwaxvsqah0bb-python-2.7.17/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py(1047)_execute_child()
-> raise child_exception
(Pdb) up 
> /nix/store/lbrpma3528hq7gwn8ffbnwaxvsqah0bb-python-2.7.17/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py(394)__init__()
-> errread, errwrite)
(Pdb) # empty is equivalent to do last command, i.e. up in this case
> /nix/store/lbrpma3528hq7gwn8ffbnwaxvsqah0bb-python-2.7.17/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py(216)check_output()
-> process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
(Pdb) print(popenargs)
(['git', 'rev-parse', '--verify', '--short', 'HEAD'],)
```

But you will find you might need to figure a way to avoid `waf` using `git` as it cannot access the network unless it's a fixed-output derivation (e.g. those fetching sources). Hopefully the bit about `fetchSubmodules` will fix it!

**Edit**: I didn’t read past that it tries to use git, it tries to figure out what version it is, you should somehow make it avoid using git to do that, e.g. grep -r 'rev-parse' suggests editing the wscript file

**Edit 2**: E.g. something like

```
--- wscript-old 2020-01-29 15:55:54.100976818 +0000
+++ wscript     2020-01-29 15:55:58.128977024 +0000
@@ -257,7 +257,7 @@
                conf.env.GIT_COMMIT = subprocess.check_output(
                        ["git", "rev-parse", "--verify", "--short", "HEAD"],
                        stderr=devnull).decode().strip()
-       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
+       except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, OSError):
                conf.env.GIT_COMMIT = ''

        conf.define("VERSION", VERSION)
```

perhaps it could be upstreamed too (this leaves the git commit ID as empty in this case)? Or just use `substituteInPlace` or something to put in the actual commit ID to be

```
--- wscript-old 2020-01-29 15:55:54.100976818 +0000
+++ wscript     2020-01-29 15:57:56.177983054 +0000
@@ -249,16 +249,7 @@

        conf.env.VERSION = VERSION

-       try:
-               import os
-
-               devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
-
-               conf.env.GIT_COMMIT = subprocess.check_output(
-                       ["git", "rev-parse", "--verify", "--short", "HEAD"],
-                       stderr=devnull).decode().strip()
-       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
-               conf.env.GIT_COMMIT = ''
+        conf.env.GIT_COMMIT = 'cec0ea76b2d5f69afa74d3ffc14a0950e32a7914'

        conf.define("VERSION", VERSION)
        conf.define("_GNU_SOURCE", 1)
```